# Jquery - Passing values to different select options

Tags: jquery, html, session-storage

I'm working on a booking engine where i have a reservation form on the homepage and after a user fills it, is redirected to the booking page.

Below is a screen-shot of the reservation form on homepage:

[image]

The 'Make Reservation' button takes you to the booking page. From this form, when a user selects the number of children, additional dropdown(s) are appended to the form which require the user to select the age of the child/children, based on number selected. e.g. if a user fills in 2 children, an additional 2 dropdowns will be appended:

[image]

On the booking page, the reservation form is presented to the user with information they filled in in the homepage. Below is a screen-shot of the booking page:

[image]

To my question now: notice how the above screen-shot of the reservation form on the booking page has the ages of the children set to 17. This is because on the homepage after selecting 2 children, for the ages, i select 9 and 17 for the two dropdowns. on the reservation form on the booking page (after clicking the 'Make Reservation' button), the two dropdowns for the children ages will be set to the value of the last selected dropdown option. So, say for example on the homepage i select 4 children, an additional 4 dropdowns will be appended to the form and if for the ages i select 5,9,6,10, then, on redirecting to the booking page, all the children ages for the 4 children will be set to 10.

For the form on the homepage, i have a div which i'm appending the age dropdowns. i.e. for the form on the homepage:

```
<div class = "display-text"></div><div id = "children-number" class="children-number"></div>
```

in my javascript file, i append the div as follows:

```
$('select[name="gdlr-children-number[]"]').on('change', function(e){
        var children_num = e.target.value;
        displayChildren(children_num);


    });

function displayChildren(children_num)
    {
        var min_num = 0;
        var max_num = 18;
        var options = '';

        options += '<select name = "age" class = "children-num">';
        options += '<option value = ""></option>';

        if(children_num == 0)
        {
            var display = $('.display-text').css('display', 'none');
        }   
        else if(children_num == 1)
        {
            var display = $('.display-text').html('<p>Age of child at check-out</p>').css('display', 'block');
        }   
        else if(children_num > 1)
        {
            var display = $('.display-text').html('<p>Ages of children at check-out</p>').css('display', 'block');
        }

        for( var i = min_num; i < max_num; i++ )
        {
            options += '<option value = '+i+' >'+i+'</option>';

        }
        options += '</select>&nbsp;';

        for(var i = 0; i<=children_num; i++)
        {
            $('select[name="gdlr-children-number[]"]').bind('change', function(){display;});

            document.getElementById("children-number").innerHTML = options.repeat(children_num);

        }
    }
```

So basically i have an 'change' listener on the children dropdown - which will execute the `displayChildren` function. the `displayChildren` function appends the select options based on number of children selected in the 'Children' dropdown. This is for the homepage

For the booking page, a check is done to see how many children are selected on- load and this is used to execute the `displayChildren` function i.e.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var children_num = $('select[name="gdlr-children-number[]"] 
     option:selected').text();

  displayChildren(children_num);
});
```

To append the age of children selected on the homepage to reflect on this reservation form, i have thought of storing the age selection in a session as:

```
$('#children-number').on('change', '.children-num', function(e){
     var child_num = e.target.value;
     sessionStorage.setItem("random", child_num);
});
```

I place this function outside the ready function and then inside the ready function, retrieve the stored item;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var children_num = $('select[name="gdlr-children-number[]"] option:selected').text();

   displayChildren(children_num);

   child_num = sessionStorage.getItem("random");
   $('.children-num').val(child_num);
});
```

This will obviously return a single value so i even tried capturing the selected ages and pushing them into an array when setting the session and looping over in sessionStorage.getItem but still, i get the value of the last selected age item.

I've tried to be as detailed as possible to make my question understandable. Thanks

- **EDIT**

Based on @xcy7e comment, i'll shorten the question:

I have a reservation form on the homepage that posts the data filled in to the booking page. The reservation form has a Children dropdown(containing values 0-17) which when selected, will append extra dropdown(s) based on the number of children selected. The appended dropdown(s) will capture the age(s) of the child/children.

The issue i'm facing is: after the dropdowns are appended to the form and selected, I'm struggling to capture that data and passing it to the booking page(as per my second screen-shot). The exact issue is that after i select the ages, the value selected for the last dropdown(say 2 children are selected, an additional 2 dropdowns will be appended for their ages to be captured. If i select 2 and 3 for these, after i submit the form, i'll get the value of both dropdowns set to 3) is what all the ages will be set to. I've laid out the code above. Hope this clears my question up

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare each select-values to retrieve the highest value.

```
var maxSelectedAge;
$('select[name="gdlr-children-number[]"] option:selected').each(function(k,v) {
   if(maxSelectedAge < parseInt($(v).val()) {
       maxSelectedAge = $(v).val();
   }
});
```

Your approach - to build an array and store this in session - will always get you the last item of the array. You could order it beforehand but storing only the values you really need is preferable (see example above)

Comment: hey @xcy7e. my aim is to get the values for children ages on the booking page as they are selected on the appended dropdowns on the homepage. not too sure what your point above addresses.

Comment: Aren't you asking for that? " (...) has the ages of the children set to 17. This is because on the homepage after selecting 2 children, for the ages, i select 9 and 17 for the two dropdowns." I don't see your text matching the given screenshots which makes your question quite unclear.

Comment: Can you reduce your question to few lines of code that does not what you'd expect it to do?